# Are apostrophes used as quotation marks still apostrophes?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

What do you call apostrophes that are used as quotation marks? For example

> ‘Yes, that’s all that happened,’ she replied.

or (Java)

> char[][] letterBlock = {{'a','b','c'},{'d','e','f'},{'g','h','i'},{'j', 'k', 'l'}};

Or do you call ‘ and ' differently?

Comment: Different computer programming languages have different names for characters; although not all give them names. C/C++ seems to use "single quotation mark". You can check documentation/standards for other languages if you're interested.

Answer (score 7):

They're called "single quotation marks" or "single quotes".

An apostrophe is just used singly for contractions, possessive 's, and the like.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question, I pasted what you typed into a word processor, and changed font and sizes to make things clearer. The symbol on the left, before 'and', is a *single opening quote*, and is ONLY used together with a *closing single quote* to enclose quoted text. This type of quote is often called a 'curly quote'.

The symbol on the right, after 'and', is a *typewriter apostrophe*, and is usually used in informal text, either as an opening or closing single quote, or as an apostrophe. It is often called a 'straight quote'.

[image]

This is a *curly closing quote*. [image] which can also be used as a more formal apostrophe.

[How to use an apostrophe](https://apostrophe.how/#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20Windows%20Alt%20%2B%200%201,fact%20insert%20the%20curly%20variant.)